# How to add running title and author

Tags: header-footer

How can I add the so-called "*running*" title and author name on the top of each page? This feature is often used in journals so that the short *running title* is shown on the top of *odd* pages and the *running author* name is shown on the even pages.

In journal style files they usually provice the `\titlerunning` and `\authorrunning` commands to do it quickly, but how can I add them myself?

And also it would be very good (almost necessary) to add a line separating this running title of the rest of a page.

Comment: Is this for an article submission, or for personal use? If it's the former, they probably have specifications/requirements you have to adhere to.

Comment: @Werner : Currently I need it for my personal use. When I submit to journal, I use the functions and style they provide, of course.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the [fancyhdr package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). The simplest approach is to set the headings manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Owl stretching time}
\author{M Python}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{M Python}
\rhead{Owl stretching time}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
abc
\newpage
def
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Using the arguments given to `\author` and `\title` is slightly more difficult, because these are cleared when `\maketitle` is executed. However, you can make copies using `\let`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Owl stretching time}
\author{M Python}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\let\runauthor\@author
\let\runtitle\@title
\makeatother
\lhead{\runauthor}
\rhead{\runtitle}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
abc
\newpage
def
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps somewhat. I obtain a running author and title (with a nice line separating them from the rest of a page), but how do I make the title appear on the odd pages only and the author - on the even pages only?

Comment: @v_2e: If you're using `twoside`, you can specify `\fancyhead[O]{...}` for `O`dd-side headings, and `\fancyhead[E]{...}` for `E`ven. Additional identifiers like `L` and `R` to denote the `L`eft or `R`ight side of the page.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot! I did `\fancyhead[LO]{Running title}` and `\fancyhead[RE]{Running author}` in combination with `twoside` document class option, and it did exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: I tried this but got nothing, @v_2e, could you copy your preamble here? Thanks!

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic --- It would be better for you to ask a new question; few people will see your comment here. Also, please explain exactly what went wrong in your case. It is unlikely that anyone will be able to help on the basis of the information you provided.

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic , here is the minimum working preamble: `\documentclass[twoside]{article}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\fancyhead[LO]{Odd-Left-text}    
\fancyhead[RE]{Even-Right-text}    
\pagestyle{fancy}`

Answer (score 2):

I had to piece together different parts of these answers to get what I needed. Two-sided, two-column, alternating left and right headers, with no header on the first page. And two-sided line numbers. You can insert a title however you want later, but the idea is that you won't want a header over your title.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside]{article}
% Line numbers package
\usepackage[switch,columnwise]{lineno}
% Creates example text
\usepackage{lipsum} 
% Headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fancyhead[LO]{My Running Title for Header}
\fancyhead[RE]{2013 Firstauthor and Secondauthor}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

This is just an expansion on the nice answers already shown here. And it works.

Comment: The header is not made to depend on the actual title provided in the document : the only trick here is that you don't specify one, so it does not answer the question