# \chapter* with a titletoc entry and a running head

Tags: hyperref, titletoc

The answer referred to above involves `Koma` and deals with a single chapter. I have not been able to make any use of the answer in my case where the document class is `book` and where I want to deal with *all* chapters.

I would like to define a `titletoc` command which, like `\chapter*` suppresses the word `Chapter` and the `chapter number` in the title of the chapter but produces both a table of content entry and a running head, both without the word `Chapter` and the `chapter number`.

As it turned out, though, the question *had* indeed been asked and, as @Johannes_B finally pointed out in a comment, an answer given at [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/creating-unnumbered-chapters-sections-plus-adding-them-to-the-toc-and-or-header) To wit, `\chapter*` need not be redefined but two lines need to be added. Seems a bit clunky but a macro to insert `chapter*` along with the two lines can do the job.

Correction: The two lines *were* given in the question referred to above, by @egreg, but hidden in a comment. :-(

Here is a MWE with the additional two necessary lines indented:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{One}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{One}
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{One}}{\MakeUppercase{One}} 
Text  
\newpage
Text  Text 
\newpage
Text  Text  Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Search for unnumberedtotoc

Comment: By the way, what has titletoc to do with that?

Comment: @Johannes_B  **1.** With MWEs, you are damned if you do and damned if you don't. :-))  I am using `titletoc` for the book so it has to work for `titletoc` **2.** I saw the suggested question but a) it involves KOMA and b) was for only _one_ chapter, namely the Introduction. That was _not_ my question which was how to redefine `\chapter*`, that is it should work for _all_ chapters---and with `hyperref`. **3.** I tried your `unnumberedtotoc.sty` but got "Illegal parameter number in definition of \addchap" And, as a LaTeX illiterate, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Probably update, or something, as the package works for most folks. ...

Comment: @Johannes_B Re. update: I downloaded it a couple of hours ago. Re. something: any suggestion? (I am really stuck.)

Comment: Update your tex distribution.

Comment: Without a clear question, it is hard to help. `titletoc` is the wrong tool, it is a screwdriver, but you need a hammer. `titletoc` has nothing to do with what you want. Anyway, `unnumberedtotoc` can help you, but you state that there is an error, but don't give a clear indication what the error is. Please edit your question and incorporate an up to date minimal working example. Also, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/creating-unnumbered-chapters-sections-plus-adding-them-to-the-toc-and-or-header I also think the answer below is very bad, one wouldn't do that.

Comment: You could just as well be looking for `frontmatter`, who know?

Answer (score 1):

"If you want to get something done well, do it yourself."

```
\phantomsection %% hyperref thingy
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} %% add to toc
\chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction} %% actual chapter invocation
\let\backupthefigure\thefigure  %% dark voodoo magic to get figure numbers go like
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{0.\arabic{figure}} %% Fig. 0.2 instead of Fig. 2
```

I used `memoir` style here, apparently the running head declaration is `memoir`-specific.

---

*Update.* The `book` style works based in MWE, however you need to adapt the style of the running heads yourself. Notice the order of `\chapter` and `addtotoc`. (It was different in my initial code, but worked there somehow, probably because of further things omitted here.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection %% hyperref thingy
\chapter*{One} %% actual chapter invocation
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{One} %% add to toc

%% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68308/how-to-add-running-title-and-author
\fancyhead[RE]{One}
%\fancyhead[LO]{2013 Firstauthor and Secondauthor}

\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Real One}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

The `memoir` class (which I used and which I regard superior to `book`) works this around the way I initially posted, here is the full code and a screenshot:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection %% hyperref thingy
\chapter*[One]{One} %% actual chapter invocation
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{One} %% add to toc

\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Real One}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: the optional parameter for chapter works for memoir]

By the way, you might consider using `microtype` and `natbib`/`biblatex`. These increase writer's productivity (when writing scientific texts) and optics of the result greatly.

Comment: I have added a MWE using your code which does produce a TOC entry but not a running head. The MWE does not include `[One]` in the`\Chapter*` command because that prints a large `[` in place of the title and `One]One Text Text Text` instead of  `text text text`

Comment: Okay, then the `\chapter*[foo]{bar}` syntax is `memoir`-specific.

Comment: Here is something on modifying running heads: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68308/how-to-add-running-title-and-author

Comment: Why are you redefining  the figure counter representation?

Comment: It was copied out of my document. There, I had the introduction as an unnumbered chapter, followed by numbered chapters. In the latter the figures were numbered like 2.12, but in the first unnumbered chapter they were numbered like 12. The redefinition fixes that. It should be canceled after the unnumbered chapter ends.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Also, the toc entries link to the chapters only when the toc is just before the end of the document. As for the question on how to modify running heads, it involves fancyhdr and the code is already "a fragile construction". Or so some say. :-))

Comment: I don't understand your toc comment, sorry. Yeah, by no means stable, but worked well for me.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I copied the MWE which has `\tableofcontents` at the end. I compiled it. When I click on the toc entry in the `pdf`, I get to the chapter. But: if I move `\tableofcontents` to _any_ other place in the source, when I click on the toc entry, I do _not_ get to the chapter. I had not thought the question was such a hard one. But it sure seems to be.

Comment: Swap the `\chapter` and `addtotoc`. I am updating my answer.

Comment: @OlegLobachev *1.* I should have thought about the swap. :-(  Anyway, I have updated the MWE accordingly but, see the question, the running head now runs throughout the book. *2.* I am really inept at LaTeX but have produced several books over the years during which I have evolved a fairly complicated structure---which I don't really understand---but which does what I want and which I do not want to change because I am old and running out of time. But, as I am often reminded, it is an increasingly fragile construction.